# How would you simplify this command?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, strace

I'm quite new to strace / netstat / etc. I'm using this command to get a trace of the apache process handling my request (telnet), is there a way to simplify it a bit?

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p $(netstat -antlp | \ 
    grep $(lsof -p `pidof telnet` | grep TCP | \
    perl -n -e'/localhost:(\d+)/ && print $1') | grep apache2 | \ 
    perl -n -e'/ESTABLISHED (\d+)/ && print $1')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this before or after you start the telnet process?

Comment: after it's started, you have to wait a few seconds for it to connect to apache, then you can run strace

Comment: If your command works, don't bother simplifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can improve on Mark Henderson's a little, with $() instead of `` and removing the grep with a better sed:

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p $(netstat -antlp | \
   sed -e "/telnet/s/^.*ESTABLISHED\ \|\/.*$//g")
```

Personally I think the backticks make it difficult to read; furthermore, they don't nest, unlike the $() syntax

Comment: +1, superior Script Fu and good learning example for some shell features.

Comment: This script `strace`s into the telnet, not into the Apache process that's serving it.

Answer (score 2):

`strace -p $(ss -npt|sed -n "/:$(ss -npt|sed -n '/telnet/s/^.*\?:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p') \+u/s/.*,\(.*\),.*/\1/p")`

As long as you only have one `telnet` running, this will `strace` the corresponding server if any.

If there isn't one (*eg* you `telnet`ed to an external server last), `strace` will fail with `strace: option requires an argument -- 'p'`

Answer (score 1):

```
strace -p $(netstat -tnp|awk -F'[ /]+' "/:$(netstat -tnp|awk -F'[ :]+' 
"/\/telnet/{print \$5}") /&&/apache2/{print \$7}")
```

Or, formatted for easier reading, and with the OP's strace flags intact:

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p $(netstat -tnp | \
awk -F'[ /]+' "/:$(netstat -tnp | awk -F'[ :]+' "/\/telnet/ \
{print \$5}") / && /apache2/ {print \$7}")
```

Breakdown, innermost first:

```
netstat -tnp | awk -F'[ :]+' "/\/telnet/ {print \$5}"
```

Show me, in without resolving IP addresses to DNS names, all active TCP connections.  Pipe that to awk, which prints the fifth field on any line ending in `/telnet`, where fields are separated by one or more spaces and colons.  This field will be the source port.

**To improve**: Could be made much more robust by adding a `| head -n 1` to the end or a `;exit` inside the action portion of the awk, but your original version lacked an equivalent, so I didn't want to make this one longer.

```
netstat -tnp | awk -F'[ /]+' "/:**** / && /apache2/ {print \$7}")
```

The `****` here is the portion I've already explained, above.  Here, I'm looking for any line in `netstat -tnp` that has the same port as the source port I discovered above, and is owned by Apache; when I find it, I print the seventh field (delimited by one or more spaces or slashes).  This is the PID of the Apache child.

**To improve**: Besides only returning one PID (via the same methods as above), the biggest thing I can imagine is being more discriminative when it comes to actually matching the dport as opposed to something else that just so happens to fit the pattern.  This would have been easy to do by adding colons to the FS (`-F`), but the problem occurs in mixed IPv4 vs. IPv6 situations, where there might be colons in the address itself, and as such could get nasty rather quickly.  This seemed pretty damn robust, especially with the trailing space.

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p
```

This is a direct copy from your original question; I didn't modify it in the least.

If you'll permit me a few extra characters, the version I'd run might be:

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p $(netstat -tnp | \
awk -F'[ /]+' "/:$(netstat -tnp | awk -F'[ :]+' "/\/telnet/ \
{print \$5;exit}") / && /apache2/ {print \$7;exit}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps:

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/strace -f -s4096 -r -p `netstat -antlp | \
  grep telnet | sed -e "s/^.*ESTABLISHED\ \|\/.*$//g"`
```

Comment: Answer would look nicer if you didn't have to scroll to the right to see it all.

Comment: This `strace`s into the `telnet`, not Apache.